# Use Vue.js plugin in js service module

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, auth0

I am creating an `$auth` plugin that works fine from the component using `this.$auth`

main.js

```
import { Auth0Plugin } from "./auth";

Vue.use(Auth0Plugin, {
  domain: process.env.VUE_APP_AUTH0_DOMAIN,
  clientId: process.env.VUE_APP_AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
  audience: process.env.VUE_APP_AUTH0_AUDIENCE,
  onRedirectCallback: () => {
    router.push("/signed-in");
  }
});
```

auth/index.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import createAuth0Client from "@auth0/auth0-spa-js";

/** Define a default action to perform after authentication */
const DEFAULT_REDIRECT_CALLBACK = () =>
  window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, window.location.pathname);

let instance;

/** Returns the current instance of the SDK */
export const getInstance = () => instance;

/** Creates an instance of the Auth0 SDK. If one has already been created, it returns that instance */
export const useAuth0 = ({
  onRedirectCallback = DEFAULT_REDIRECT_CALLBACK,
  redirectUri = window.location.origin,
  ...options
}) => {
  if (instance) return instance;

  // The 'instance' is simply a Vue object
  instance = new Vue({
    data() {
      return {
        loading: true,
        isAuthenticated: false,
        user: {},
        auth0Client: null,
        popupOpen: false,
        error: null
      };
    },
    methods: {
      /** Returns the access token. If the token is invalid or missing, a new one is retrieved */
      getTokenSilently(o) {
        return this.auth0Client.getTokenSilently(o);
      },
    },
    /** Use this lifecycle method to instantiate the SDK client */
    async created() {
      // Create a new instance of the SDK client using members of the given options object
      this.auth0Client = await createAuth0Client({
        domain: options.domain,
        client_id: options.clientId,
        audience: options.audience,
        redirect_uri: redirectUri
      });

      try {
        // If the user is returning to the app after authentication..
        if (
          window.location.search.includes("code=") &&
          window.location.search.includes("state=")
        ) {
          // handle the redirect and retrieve tokens
          const { appState } = await this.auth0Client.handleRedirectCallback();

          // Notify subscribers that the redirect callback has happened, passing the appState
          // (useful for retrieving any pre-authentication state)
          onRedirectCallback(appState);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        this.error = e;
      } finally {
        // Initialize our internal authentication state
        this.isAuthenticated = await this.auth0Client.isAuthenticated();
        this.user = await this.auth0Client.getUser();
        this.loading = false;
      }
    }
  });

  return instance;
};

// Create a simple Vue plugin to expose the wrapper object throughout the application
export const Auth0Plugin = {
  install(Vue, options) {
    Vue.prototype.$auth = useAuth0(options);
  }
};
```

I have a service class that calls an api.
I need to get the api token from this plugin `$auth.getTokenSilently()`.
How do I call the instantiated plugin from my `api-service.js` file?

I know the below code doesn't work.
But it's just to demonstrate what I'm trying to do.
utils/api-service.js

```
export default {
  init() {
    this.lqdApi = axios.create({
      baseURL: process.env.lqdApiBaseUrl,
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${$auth.getTokenSilently()}` }
    });
    return this;
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The service should be initialized inside Vue. It can just be injected with initialization data:

```
  init(token) {
    this.lqdApi = axios.create({
      baseURL: process.env.lqdApiBaseUrl,
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }
    });
    return this;
  },
```

The problem here is that `async created` is a potential antipattern, it doesn't prevent child components from being initialized when `auth0Client` and therefore `api-service` aren't ready but used by components. If this is the case, one of possible solutions is to make Axios instance available on Vue prototype, like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59937352/3731501). The instance needs to be created immediately, but a token can be provided to it asynchronously with interceptors because they support promises. 
It can be written as a plugin and become available on Vue instance like `$auth`:

```
  install(Vue, options) {
    Vue.prototype.$axios = axios.create();
  },
  created() {
    if (this.$root === this) {
      this.$axios.interceptors.request.use(async config => {
        let auth0Client = await this.auth0ClientPromise;
        config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${auth0Client.getTokenSilently()}`;
        return config;
    }
  }
```

And a promise of Auth0 client instance should be available on Vue instance in order to be chained by Axios (and probably other things that may depend on it):

```
  this.auth0ClientPromise = createAuth0Client(...);
  this.auth0Client = await auth0ClientPromise;
```

Comment: where do I put the `install` and `created` functions? should I call `createAuth0Client()` from main.js or from where ever I'm creating my axios plugin?

Comment: The code was written with assumption that you still have Auth0Plugin working the way it is. 2 lines that mention createAuth0Client are supposed to replace this line, `this.auth0Client = await createAuth0Client(...)`. install and created functions are supposed to be put to separate plugin, AxiosPlugin or so.

Comment: So basically I instantiate the auth/index.js in two places? Once when creating the vue plugin and again in the js file?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. What you listed in auth/index.js is a plugin. Plugins are used once with Vue.use. The first snippet is another plugin, you can call it axios.js or whatever you like. And yes, second snippet goes to auth/index.js.

Comment: And the third code block just stays in auth/index.js? Or are you saying I should put in somewhere else too?